# How can i get taxonomy vocabulary by node_type

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, taxonomy

I have few node types and some of them have an extra field is linked to taxonomy vocabulary. How can i get taxonomy vocabulary id or  name if i know field name and node type where this field there exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Drupal 7 fields can be added to any entity/bundle, and for a term reference field the vocabularies used are set on the field level, *not* on the entity/bundle level.

So you don't need to query the field settings for a particular content type, but simply the settings for the field itself. The vocabulary machine names are stored in the `allowed_values` key of the `settings` array returned from [`field_info_field()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.info.inc/function/field_info_field/7):

```
$field_name = 'field_name_of_field';
$info = field_info_field($field_name);

$vocab_keys = array();
foreach ($info['settings']['allowed_values'] as $item) {
  $vocab_keys[] = $item['vocabulary'];
}

// $vocab_keys now contains an array of all vocabulary machine names allowed on this field
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Cool! Thx for sharing about `field_info_field` function =)

Comment: @VladStratulat: No problem :) There's a whole bunch of helpful field info functions in `/modules/field/field.info.inc` if you're interested

Answer (score 0):

This code is useful if you keep term in your extra field.

```php
/**
 * Get vocabulary ID by term name applied to node
 */
$tid = $node->your_field[$node->language][0]['tid'];
$term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);

/* $term now is the following object
stdClass Object(
    [tid] => 1
    [vid] => 1
    [name] => Name of term
    [description] => Description of term
    [format] => full_html
    [weight] => 0
    [vocabulary_machine_name] => vocabulary
) */

/**
 * Loading vocabularies
 */
$vocabularies = taxonomy_get_vocabularies();

/* $vocabularies now is the following array
Array(
    [1] => stdClass Object(
        [vid] => 1
        [name] => Forums
        [machine_name] => forums
        [description] => Forum navigation vocabulary
        [hierarchy] => 1
        [module] => forum
        [weight] => -10
    )
    [2] => stdClass Object(
        [vid] => 2
        [name] => Category
        [machine_name] => category
        [description] => 
        [hierarchy] => 1
        [module] => taxonomy
        [weight] => -9

    )
) */

/**
 * Vocabulary searched by you
 */
$vocabulary = $vocabularies[$term->vid];

/* $vocabulary now is the following object
Array(
    [1] => stdClass Object(
        [vid] => 1
        [name] => Forums
        [machine_name] => forums
        [description] => Forum navigation vocabulary
        [hierarchy] => 1
        [module] => forum
        [weight] => -10
    )
) */
```